# python36._pth isn't being recognized

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I'm using python36 on windows installed without admin privs.

I create a simple script, `tester.py`

```
import petl as etl
fnar = [['foo','bar'],
        ['weebl','woobl']]
print(etl.fromcolumns(fnar).lookall())
```

on the commandline, I install petl to a directory.

`pip install petl -t lib`

And when I check, it's in there.

```
2017-04-17  06:27 PM    <DIR>          petl
2017-04-17  06:27 PM    <DIR>          petl-1.1.1.dist-info
```

I want to use that directory to find my petl, so I create a [python36._pth file](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-modules).

```
.
lib
import site
```

When I try to run my script, it can't find it!

```
>py tester.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 2, in <module>
    import petl as etl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'petl'
```

What am I misunderstanding about getting ._pth files to work?

Comment: Where is your `._pth` file? Where is your script? What is the name of your actual Python executable and your Python dll and where do they live?

Comment: Why are you using a `._pth` file, which is meant for embedding Python, instead of normal .pth files or `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: You're creating a `.pth` that overrides the entire Python `sys.path`. Instead you need to create one as described in the [`site.py` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site),

Comment: my ._pth file is in the same directory as my tester.py script. 
My actual executable is in C:\Users\mattk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe

Comment: I'm just trying to add the lib directory as the place to find petl for this script tester.py.

Comment: A ._pth file gets created alongside the executable for applications that are embedding Python and need complete control over `sys.path`. If you just want a particular path added, then create a regular .pth file in the system or user site-packages. This feature depends on importing `site`, so it won't work with the -S command-line option (and also -I for the user site-packages, i.e. `site.getusersitepackages()`). Adding the directory to `PYTHONPATH` doesn't depend on importing `site`, but -I isolated mode will ignore it, and it also affects every version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `.pth` files only get evaluated if they are placed in one of the standard locations shown by `python -m site`, *other* than the current working directory. I can't remember the details, but I think Python runs through these standard locations first, running any .pth files it finds there, then adds `''` (current working directory) to the start of `sys.path` afterward. This means you can't extend the path just by adding a `.pth` file in the directory you launch your script from.

The only way that I know to add relative locations to the system path is to set them at the top of your main script, before your `import` statements. In this case, you could do that with something like `sys.path.append( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))`.